# Hot to use prependTo on multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I try to move the div of .date above the div of .title using the jQuery prependTo method but I did not make it work.

I tried this:

```
jQuery(".date").prependTo(".title");
```

but I have multiple .title divs.
And this without luck:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('.date').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).prependTo(jQuery(this).closest('.title'));
     });
});
```

My code is

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="tag">Tag</span>
        <span class="title">Text 01</span>
    </a>
    <div class="category">My category</div>
    <div class="date">September 2019</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="tag">Tag</span>
        <span class="title">Text 01</span>
    </a>
    <div class="category">My category 2</div>
    <div class="date">Nov 2019</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="tag">Tag</span>
        <span class="title">Text 01</span>
    </a>
    <div class="category">My category3</div>
    <div class="date">Dec 2019</div>
  </li>    
</ul>
```

I expect this result:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="tag">Tag</span>
        <div class="date">September 2019</div>
        <span class="title">Text 01</span>
    </a>
    <div class="category">My category</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="tag">Tag</span>
        <div class="date">Nov 2019</div>
        <span class="title">Text 01</span>
    </a>
    <div class="category">My category 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="tag">Tag</span>
        <div class="date">Dec 2019</div>
        <span class="title">Text 01</span>
    </a>
    <div class="category">My category3</div>  
  </li>    
</ul>
```

Any help?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `jQuery(this).closest('li').find('.title')` or `jQuery(this).parent().find('.title')` because `.title` is not a parent of `.date`

Like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.date').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).prependTo(jQuery(this).closest('li').find('.title'));
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.date').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).prependTo(jQuery(this).closest('li').find('.title'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="tag">Tag</span>
      <span class="title">Text 01</span>
    </a>
    <div class="category">My category</div>
    <div class="date">September 2019</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="tag">Tag</span>
      <span class="title">Text 01</span>
    </a>
    <div class="category">My category 2</div>
    <div class="date">Nov 2019</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="tag">Tag</span>
      <span class="title">Text 01</span>
    </a>
    <div class="category">My category3</div>
    <div class="date">Dec 2019</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```